# Disk space issue in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, diskspace

i am new to rabbitmq. I tried to push 1 million sample message into my queue.

I have installed RabbitMQ on C drive. But while running the process due to the disk space issue in `C`  drive the process got struck and i purged the queue.

My question is, Is there a way to change the location where the message to be stored.

In my case i have 500 GB of `D` drive and i want to use that drive. How can i do this.

I have used Python client

```
for i in range (0,1000000):

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'"


connection.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define environment variables. See the RabbitMQ documentation about [File Locations](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html) and especialy `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE` environment variable:

> This base directory contains sub-directories for the RabbitMQ server's
>   Mnesia database files, one for each node, unless RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR
>   is set explicitly. (In addition to Mnesia files this location also
>   contains message storage and index files as well as schema and cluster
>   details.)

for you case something like `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE=d:\rabbitmq\db`